# Connect to docker socket from within container

Tags: docker, sockets

I'm running a docker-compose setup via Laravel Sail where I'd like to access the docker socket from within the container.

I've added the `/var/run/docker.sock` socket to the volumes but when I try to access the socket through curl it replies with `curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server`:

```
$ curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/version

reply: curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

This is part of my docker-compose.yml file:

```yaml
services:
    laravel.test:
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't replicate your issue. When I try, it works as expected.

Comment: The Docker socket is owned by the root user.  If you want access to that Unix socket from within the container, you should ensure that the user is root or is included in the docker group.

Comment: @DanielCampos You're right, `/var/run/docker.sock` belongs to `root` and the user inside the container is `sail`. How do I set the `docker.sock` user inside the container to my current user? If I run `RUN chmod +x /var/run/docker.sock` it returns `No such file or directory` (I know that's not setting the user btw :) )

Comment: Of course, because you're mounting the volume on the created image, but at the time of building the image that doesn't exist yet. 

I know your problem, I'll explain it in detail in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you're trying to access an Unix socket owned by `root`, as it's `/var/run/docker.sock` with a different user than `root`.

Only thing you should do is to create a group `docker` in the image you want to use and to add the user of the image to that group, since the Socket is also owned by the `docker` group.

```
srw-rw----  1 root  docker     0 Jul 29 07:51 docker.sock
```

**Dockerfile**

> DO NOT USE THIS, AS @David Maze COMENTED THE GID OF THE CREATED DOCKER GROUP COULD NOT MATCH THE GID FROM THE HOST.

```
FROM ...

USER root
RUN groupadd docker
RUN usermod -aG docker sail

USER sail
...
```

**Docker Compose v3**

Docker Compose on its format version v2 had the possibility of including `group_add` but that's not an option anymore in v3.

Even if you could jut use the version 2 of the compose, there's an option of doing it with the v3.

```
services:
    laravel.test:
        user: "sail:${GIP}"
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

When you're going to start your containers with `docker-compose up -d`, export first the group ID for the `docker` group in your host machine.

```
export GIP=$(cut -d: -f3 < <(getent group docker))
docker-compose up -d
```

Then your `sail` user will have access to `/var/run/docker.sock` and to all the Docker CLI commands.

Also, keep in mind that the `docker` group grants privileges equivalent to the `root` user. Take a look on [*Docker Daemon Attack Surface*](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface) to be conscious about the security impact that could have in your system.

Comment: The _numeric_ group ID of the container process has to match the _numeric_ group ID owning the socket file.  The name of the group doesn't matter.  That gid will be different across different hosts and it's not something you can set in the Dockerfile.  Compose file v2 (but not v3) has a [`group_add:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#group_add) option that might be a better match.

Comment: You're totally right, the GID could not be the same for the `docker` group in the container and in the host, and then it wouldn't work. On another hand, the use of Compose v3 is more orientated towards Docker Swarm, it's okay to use v2 if you require features from it.